# Java 8 : Map Lambda expression

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8

I have a `Map<String, List<Object>> multiFieldMap` and I need to itereate over its value set and add the value to `multiFieldsList` as below

```
public List<Object> fetchMultiFieldsList() {
    List<Object> multiFieldsList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : multiFieldMap.entrySet()) {
        String entityName = entry.getKey();
        List<Object> ids = entry.getValue();
        for (Object id : ids) {
            Object entity = queryService.query(entityName, queryService.property("id").eq(id));
            multiFieldsList.add(entity);
        }
    }
    return multiFieldsList;
}
```

Am wondering can this method be simplified further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Streams API :

```
List<Object> multiFieldsList = 
    multiFieldMap.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .flatMap(e -> e.getValue()
                                .stream()
                                .map(o -> queryService.query(e.getKey(), queryService.property("id").eq(o))))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is typically a case where I personally think that a full stream solution is actually less readable than a "good old" foreach loop :p

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use a stream to simplify you inner loop.

You can replace:

```
List<Object> ids = entry.getValue();
for (Object id : ids) {
    Object entity = queryService.query(entityName, queryService.property("id").eq(id));
    multiFieldsList.add(entity);
}
```

with:

```
entry.getValue().map(
    id -> queryService.query(entityName, queryService.property("id").eq(id))
).forEach(multiFieldsList::add);
```

But you don't really gain much from that. Your choice...

See @Eran's answer for a "full stream" solution.

Comment: Code simplification does not always need `Stream` API use…

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it like this:

```
public List<Object> fetchMultiFieldsList() {
    List<Object> multiFieldsList = new ArrayList<>();
    multiFieldMap.forEach( (entityName, ids ) ->
        ids.forEach( id -> multiFieldsList.add(
            queryService.query(entityName, queryService.property("id").eq(id)))
        )
    );
    return multiFieldsList;
}
```

Unless you want to use the `Stream` API, the method [`Map.forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) might be the biggest win regarding code simplification as you don’t need to deal with `Map.Entry` and its generic signature anymore…